# Fix bricked Lumia (Black Screen, No vibrtion, Detected by computer as 'USB Input Device' for sometime after rebooting)

Tags: recovery-tool

I had been tampering my Nokia Lumia 625 since a while with WPinternals. Just like a fool, I restarted my phone (by long pressing only power button) while it was in the middle of flashing an unlocked bootloader in QHSUSB_ARMPRG mode. I did so, because I got frustrated of the long time it was taking (It got suck at 21%). I knew that from QHSUSB_ARMPRG mode, long pressing power button takes the phone into flash mode, but this time it didn't because it was flashing something. I could have easily just unplugged the cable to go into QHSUSB_DLOAD mode from which reverting back is easy!

What happened next? The phone went into an unresponsive state. I can do nothing. No button combinations give life (No vibrations). It's in a complete black screen. Connecting it to a computer after rebooting by pressing power button for 10 seconds makes it get detected as 'USB Input Device' just for a few seconds and after that it's no one. Both Windows Device Recovery Tool and thor2 won't detect it while its in USB Input Device.
My Conclusion: The Bootloader's got corrupted. I myself cannot fix it; I've tried almost all methods I know. Now I need your help to fix it before I take it to a service center to get it JTAGed. 
Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Go ask for help in their store... But your Device os kinda Old so you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Having gone through such stage (**bricked my Lumia 1020 about 2 months ago**). I know the longing to get things working again. You wish to rollback in time.

In my case, I was 'again' upgrading my device to Windows 10 Mobile. Using WPInternal's because Windows Phone 8.xx.xxx has almost reached the end of its journey. I'm missing so many awesome apps which are being gradually knoced-out from the WP8 platform. It almost looks like virtual-suicide to me. This is happening in Win 10 Mobile platform, but more slowly.

**Anyways, How/why my LUMIA 1020 got bricked**

1. Somewhere during flashing I heard USB Disconnect sound.
   (Felt f**ked up) LoL.
2. Followed by Windows message - "WPInternals not responding"
3. I confirmed that My Lumia is (was) bricked. Nothing on screen, no vibration- No direct signs of life (Direct I'm saying). I behaved as you did, cried to god also :P

USB Port on my Lumia was not working properly. Actually, it worked at a critical angle flipped down, strange, but working. I tried to clean port with alcohol, took out some micro fibres stuck inside. But it don;t want to be normal + Data cables at my disposal were too old to be working with that

**Loose USB Port* - This might(99.99%) have caused diconnection during flashing operation resulting in Bricked Phone, in my case**

I had never seen a bricked phone in my life, before. So, I wanted to know why this happened.

(Telling you this because if solution below doesn't work & you still want to revive it, keep digging. Otherwise buy a new phone if you can)

**Solution:**

> This 'might' work only if you are getting ***QHS_USB_QDLoad (or something similar) in your Device manager***. i.e.- Device manager should be detecting your device (even for 1 second, as in my case)

[image: Device Manager>Ports>]

---

- Install **Windows Device Recovery Tool** (WDRT) from **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq)**
- Also, **Download the "Emergency files" for your phone** from [LumiaFirmware.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRSsk.png). Search/Browse from the list your **RM-94x - Lumia 625**

  `It is  very important to choose correct RM-94x for your device. Otherwise you might face other terrible problems.`

  **Select appropriate Product code from the list** shown on right for related RM-94x
  *I've choosen RM-875,etcetra here as an example. If you're having problem finding your product code, try googling or ask someone, before proceeding*

  **Download & Save all the Firmware Files** and **Emergency Files** *(Marked in Blue Box)*

  Skip Firmware files if you are having Firmware downloaded already from WDRT or elsewhere.

  > **Save all the 'downloaded files' in single-folder in ...\Products\RM-94x\ directory**
- Make sure to **CHARGE YOUR DEVICE ATLEAST 1-hour** before proceeding, even if its not working

> (e.g.: I've RM-875 in my case, in Downloads\Products\RM-875)

3. **Launch WDRT** *(You should have working internet connection as s/w looks for updates)*
4. Go to **Settings>Packages>** Set 'Use custom path packages' to ON and browse upto the folder where 'Products' is located. and **Restart WDRT**
5. If WDRT not selected automatically, **Select- My device was not detected** (Since your device is bricked it won't be detected by WDRT, probably)
   **Your Device will appear as "RM-94x blah!". Select it.**
6. Tadaa!! Let the WDRT do its job. Do-not-Disturb anything.

> Flashing in Windows needs switching to Emergency Download Mode, that's why we needed Emergency Files.

[image: Microsoft Website for Windows Device Recovery Tool]
[image: Download Firmware & Emergency Files]
[[image: WDRT-Settings>Packages>[6]]
[image: WDRT- My device was not detected]

Comment: NOTE: If you think you've downloaded firmware files through WDRT earlier you'll find them at this default location: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products\..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that must be easy to fix with [Windows Device Recovery tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525569). However, I ain't sure if Microsoft still supports your device. If in case your device isn't detected or this method didn't work then you'd have to manually install Lumia 625's firmware. It can be easily found at www.lumiafirmware.com. Please check the model number of your device. Example, if it's RM-941, then you can download it from [lumiafirmware.com/ser/RM-941](http://www.lumiafirmware.com/ser/RM-941)

Comment: To install a firmware (Flash an .ffu file) by both manually or by WDRT tool, I must have access to the Flash mode. But as I said, I haven't got a bootloader on my device, but the rest of the OS is installed. I just need to flash a bootloader, but how? that's the question,.